# Retrofit not fetching json data from api

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am fetching `json` data from `api` using `retrofit` and I am implemented it properly using a tutorial on retrofit but i don't know why it is not fetching data.
Here is my main Class:

```
    List<noti_sec> noti_list;
    ImageView down_img;
    TextView heading_txt;

    String sessionId ;
    String userId;
    Handler handler;

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cinsio_notif);


        final RecyclerView  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.noti_recyle);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        heading_txt =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.heading_txt);
        down_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.down_img);

        heading_txt.setText("Notifications");

        down_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CinsioNotif.this, CinsioMain.class);
                //startActivity(i);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_down,R.anim.slide_out_down);
            }
        });


        // recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("USER", MODE_PRIVATE);
        sessionId = preferences.getString("session", "");
        userId=preferences.getString("id","");




        notiIterface apiService =
                ApiClient.getClient().create(notiIterface.class);



        Call<full_noti_sec> call = apiService.getNotification(userId,"",sessionId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<full_noti_sec>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<full_noti_sec> call, Response<full_noti_sec> response) {
                List<noti_sec> notif = response.body().getData();

                Log.d(TAG, "Number of notification received: " + notif.size());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new noti_adapter(notif,getApplicationContext(),R.layout.noti_msg_screen));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<full_noti_sec> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });


    }
```

My adpater class:

```
    List<noti_sec> noti_list;
    private Context context;
    private int rowLayout;
    //Constructor of this class

    public noti_adapter(List<noti_sec> noti_list, Context context,int rowLayout){
        super();
        //Getting all superheroes
        this.noti_list = noti_list;
        this.context = context;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    }


    public static class notiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CircleImageView profile_pic;
        TextView name;
        TextView about_noti;
        TextView noti_time;
        ImageView from;


        public notiViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);




            profile_pic = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            about_noti = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.notif_about);
            noti_time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noti_time);
            from = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_img);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public noti_adapter.notiViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new notiViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(notiViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        ;
        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("USER", 0);
        String fname = preferences.getString("firstname", "");
        String lname = preferences.getString("lastname", "");
        String uname = preferences.getString("username", "");
        String img = preferences.getString("imgname", "");
        String id = preferences.getString("id", "");

        String image = "http://chikoop.com/api/uploads/" + id + "/" + noti_list.get(position).getImgname();


        holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.border_frame1);
        holder.name.setText(noti_list.get(position).getUsername());
        holder.about_noti.setText(noti_list.get(position).getNoti_msg());

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(image)
                .into(holder.from);


        //holder.from.setImageResource(noti_list.get(position).getFor_image());
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return noti_list.size();
    }
```

My interface class:

```html
public interface notiIterface {
    @GET("user/get_notifications")
    Call<full_noti_sec> getNotification(@Query("userid") String userid,@Query("notification_id") String notiid, @Query("session") String apiKey);
}
```

I tried everything but my layout showing nothing.Both session and userID are correct.  Thanxx in advanced

Comment: Debug your code. Check what was really returned by web service. Add [logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) and see reponse

Comment: actual i dont know how can i check that bcz i m using retrofit for 1st time.

Comment: I've gave you the link on loggin interceptor - start with it.

Comment: write a log in onFailure maybe you get error from server.